# Javascript variable value as number in html class name

Tags: javascript, html, variables

i want to put the variable 'i' in this code:

```
do {
$('.dot:nth-child(1)').click(function(){
  $('.inside').animate({
    'width' : (i*width)+'%'
  }, 500);
});    
i++;
}
while (i <= number);
```

like this - but it don't work:

```
do {
$('.dot:nth-child('+ i +')').click(function(){
  $('.inside').animate({
    'width' : (i*width)+'%'
  }, 500);
});    
i++;
}
while (i <= number);
```

Comment: Maybe make the class stuff and javascript variable a separate variable, then pass that variable to the jquery?

Answer (score 0):

This is the classic closure issue: The function you pass to `click` has an *enduring reference* to the `i` variable, not a *copy* of it as of when the function is created. So all of your `click`s end up using the value of `i` *when the click occurs* (after the loop finishes).

The usual solution is to use a builder function:

```
do {
  $('.dot:nth-child('+ i +')').click(buildHandler(i));    
  i++;
}
while (i <= number);

function buildHandler(index) {
  return function(){
    $('.inside').animate({
      'width' : (index*width)+'%'
    }, 500);
  };
}
```

---

That said, in this case, you don't need different handler functions for each element; instead, just have *one* handler function that checks to see which child it's dealing with:

```
$('.dot').click(function(){
  var index = $(this).index();
  $('.inside').animate({
    'width' : (index*width)+'%'
  }, 500);
});
```

More: [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index)